# Python subprocess popen [Errno 24] Too many open files

Tags: python, multithreading, subprocess, popen

My python scrip calls external command to build an Ocaml project, but I am running into this problem of too many file opened

```
  try:
     handle = subprocess.Popen(['ocamlc', file_i], \
                               stdout=subprocess.PIPE, \
                               stderr=devnull, \
                               cwd=dir_o, \
                               close_fds=True
                           )
  except Exception as e:
     handle = e
     print(e)
```

file_i is an input generated by

```
for file in os.listdir(dir_i):
```

and devnull is from

```
devnull = open(os.devnull, 'w')
```

When I print the error it would display

```
[Errno 24] Too many open files
```

I don't have any files open other than devnull. So I am confused why I am getting this exception.

**Update**

```
104       # process_count += 1
105       # if process_count == MAX_PROCESS:

107       #    for p in processes:
108       #       if p != Exception:
109       #          p.wait()
110       #    process_count = 0
111       #    p = []
```

Comment: `p != Exception` should be `not isinstance(p,Exception)`.

Answer (score 0):

When calling `popen` it will not block until the external program has executed. An ocaml instances will be executed the same time for each file in `dir_i`. The operating system can only handle a certain amount of open files at the same time, so you are probably reaching this limit.

If it is possible, you could change the code to wait for each `popen` to finish. Maybe by using subprocess's `wait` or `call` methods.

Comment: @j-p-petersen, I tried using p.wait(), but my program still runs of fd. Please look at my updated post

Comment: how large is MAX_PROCESS?

Comment: I am using a virtual machine running on Ubuntu 16.04, I tried 500, 250, 100, and 50